# PHP + SSH: Interactive Shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh

I am using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to run commands via SSH *on another server*. I am currently using the Interactive Shell example (See [Here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html))

If I want to send a command, I use `$ssh->write("ls -la\n");` and then I run `$ansi->appendString($ssh->read()); echo $ansi->getScreen();` to see the screen output.

Is there a way for me to run commands from a form where can I use it like a web-based console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes why not! Then you have to implement a form and send the command to your server. But there is a much easier way. Perhaps with ajax and fetch the return from your command line.

http://www.web-console.org/

There are a lot of projects doing exact that. When you build that on your own you have to look at security and much more.

Comment: I want my website to connect to my home server via SSH though. web-console is only if I want the commands I run to run on that server.

Comment: I am looking for something exactly like web-console but can connect to another server via SSH.